# How to encrypt data using the iOS secure element?

Tags: ios, keychain, objective-c

I would like to know if there's a way to encrypt/decrypt data using the iOS secure element chip (Java card). Or does the keychain already use it?

Answer (score 1):

The keychain already uses it.

From WWDC 2015:

> We also moved the KeyStore component from the kernel into Secure Enclave and it's that component which controls the cryptography around Keychain items and the data protection.

[Source](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/706?q=security)